# IBM ServerGuide: bootable USB key?

Tags: ibm, usb-boot

Have a couple of IBM xSeries x3250s that did not come with a CD/DVD drive.  Searching around, not seeing anything tangible as far as for as a USB bootable version of ServerGuide.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an RSA/IMM card, you could mount the install media remotely

Comment: Ended up using the IMM to mount an ISO off my workstation.  Oddest thing: tried the Bootable Media Creator from IBM on two USB keys, non-bootable in either one.  Use the same ISO over IMM mount, boots no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered buying a USB-cdrom drive? That is how I deal with servers without DVD-drives.

Comment: Have one, won't detect it for some reason, regardless of what media I use, what boot options I choose (tried both USB and CD/DVD).  Infuriating since I've used it for dozens of other machines in the past.

Comment: Have you checked if a newer firmware/bios is available for the server?